# Select Nth Row From A Table In Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I select the Nth row from a table in Oracle?

I tried

```
SELECT PRICE FROM AAA_PRICING WHERE ROWNUM = 2
```

but that didn't work. Please help!

Comment: @zerkms, "didn't work" mean result set is empty

Comment: @Michael Pakhantsov: I have no oracle now, but any reason for that?

Comment: @tobyodavies but very common in SQL

Comment: but not generally in the rest of the question, which is what i was complaining about, and had thankfully been fixed.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Based on the classic answer:

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:127412348064

```
select * 
  from ( select a.*, rownum rnum
           from ( YOUR_QUERY_GOES_HERE -- including the order by ) a
          where rownum <= N_ROWS )
 where rnum >= N_ROWS
/
```

Comment: So nesting your query 3 deep is the best way to select a single result from the set?  Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: not sure about more recent versions of Oracle, but up until 10g that was the way to do it.

Comment: Why not like this ? select a.* from
(select b.*, rownum rnum from yourquery AND rownum <= N_ROWS  order by yourorderby) a
where rnum >=N_ROWS ;

Comment: hi @davek i am getting column ambigutiy when i pasted my query into query(YOUR_QUERY_GOES_HERE -- including the order by) below is my error


SQL Error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"

Answer (score 13):

Will not works with '=' (will works <2 or >2, but not equal)

so you can

```
 SELECT Price from (SELECT PRICE, ROWNUM AS RN FROM AAA_PRICING) WHERE RN = 2
```

Comment: @zerkms See sjngm's answer for an explanation.

Comment: While this will return correct results, @davek's answer is more efficient.

Answer (score 7):

To address the reason for this:

The `RowNum` is a pseudo-column supplied by Oracle. It is generated while the SELECT-clause is being processed. Since the WHERE-clause is handled *before* the SELECT-clause, the `RowNum` does not have a proper value yet.

One can argue whether or not it makes sense to have Oracle throw an exception in situation, but because `RowNum` still is a pseudo-column it's still valid to have it there.

Note: Don't confuse this with `RowId`, which is an entire different story!

IMPORTANT EDIT:

Note that what I wrote about `RowNum` is only true for `=`, `>`, `>=`, `IN ()` and maybe others. If you check for, e.g. `RowNum < 10`, you only get nine records!? I don't know why that is the case!

Comment: "you only get nine records!?" Well duh - if you start counting 1, 2, 3, ... how many numbers are there that are less than 10?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Read the last line in the second paragraph again.

Comment: Well, that statement is incorrect. ROWNUM gets assigned a value once all other predicates have been evaluated - otherwise you wouldn't be able to refer to it in the where clause.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Please try it out yourself. `SELECT MyColumn FROM MyTable WHERE RowNum > 10` vs. `SELECT MyColumn FROM MyTable WHERE RowNum < 10`. `RowNum` seems to only be incremented when the row matches the WHERE-clause. Therefore, `RowNum > 10` will never work as `RowNum` won't even become 1.

Comment: You can't use rownum>10.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Correct :) This is also true for `=`, `>`, `>=`, `IN ()`.

Comment: So, are you still confused why you only get nine records?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp No, I was only surprised to get any records at all as all other expressions didn't work. Four years ago those things amazed me...

Answer (score 3):

```
Select * From
(
    Select Row_Number() OVER (Order by empno) rno, e.* 
    From scott.emp e
)
Where rno in (1, 3, 11)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT PRICE 
FROM (  
  SELECT PRICE,    
  ROWNUM rnum 
  FROM AAA_PRICING
  ORDER BY PRICE ASC
  ) 
WHERE    rnum = 2
```

Comment: While this will return correct results, @davek's answer is more efficient.

Comment: This does not give the right answer because the rownum is determined before the "order by", not after.  You need the extra level, with the "order-by" inside, and the "rownum" outside, to make the rownums match the order.

Answer (score 1):

`ROWNUM` is a pseudo column which generates unique pseudo values (equals to the number of records present in the `SELECT` statement o/p) during the execution of `SELECT` clause. When this pseudo column is specified with the `WHERE` clause it's value becomes `1` by default. So it behaves according to the comparison operator specified with it.

```
SELECT * FROM (
           SELECT ROWNUM RN, E.*
           FROM Emp E
          )
WHERE RN = 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Oracle 12 or above, You can use the result offset and fetch clauses:

```
SELECT PRICE FROM AAA_PRICING 
offset 1 rows fetch next 1 rows only
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT PRICE, ROWNUM AS RN FROM AAA_PRICING )
WHERE RN = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (Select Price, rownum as rn from(Select * from AAA_PRICING a order by a.Price))
where rn=2;
```

It will give you 2nd lowest price from the Price column. If you want simply 2nd row remove Order By condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
From (select PRICE, DENSE_RANK() over(ORDER BY PRICE desc) as RNO
      From AAA_PRICING
     ) t where RNO=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*, rownum rnum
           from ( select * from xyz_menu order by priority desc) a
          where rownum < 5 ;
```

> select * from xyz_menu order by priority desc
>
> creating virtual table and also defining row number in virtual table

**note: for oracle**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using OFFSET AND FETCH clauses.

> OFFSET will skip first n rows in a result and FETCH will limit the output
> to n rows

So if you want to get only the 2nd row of your result, you
can filter using:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
OFFSET 1 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Also keep in mind that you need to use ORDER BY clause if your result is not sorted, else results might not be as expected.

** specifically for Oracle SQL

Answer (score 0):

Try following query:

SELECT * FROM AAA_PRICING where rownum < n + 1
MINUS
SELECT * FROM AAA_PRICING where rownum < n;

Answer (score -2):

Problem solved!

To select 2nd row in Oracle..

```
select SEN_NO,ITEM_NO from (select * from master_machine where 
sen_no ='BGCWKKL23'  and rownum <=2 order by 
rownum desc,timestamp asc) where rownum <=1
```

Thank You!

Comment: -1 This doesn't select the "2nd row", and "order by rownum" doesn't make any sense (rowsets are *always* ordered by rownum by definition!).