# Get the specific row data on Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get the specific row data.
but in this query it shows me the error.In here i want to get 5th row

> ORA-00904: "RN": invalid identifier

Code

```
   SELECT NEWSDATE,ROWNUM AS RN
   FROM NEWS
   WHERE NEWSNO='100000' AND (CAT='LR' OR CRT ='LD') AND RN = 5 //<-- It highlighted this RN is invalid
   ORDER BY  NEWSDATE ASC
```

Comment: You can't use column aliases in the `WHERE` clause. (WHERE is evaluated before the select list, logically.)

Comment: check out :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509167/select-nth-row-from-a-table-in-oracle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from (
  SELECT NEWSDATE,row_number() over (order by newsdate) AS RN
  FROM   NEWS
  WHERE  NEWSNO='100000' AND (CAT='LR' OR CRT ='LD')
)
where rn = 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use column aliases defined in the `SELECT` clause in the `WHERE` clause as the `WHERE` clause is evaluated first. To make your query syntactically valid it would be:

```
SELECT   NEWSDATE,ROWNUM AS RN
FROM     NEWS
WHERE    NEWSNO='100000' AND (CAT='LR' OR CRT ='LD') AND ROWNUM = 5
ORDER BY NEWSDATE ASC
```

However, this will never return any rows as will consider the first row produced and discard it as `ROWNUM=1` and then it will consider the second row produced and, since the first was discarded, this will also have `ROWNUM=1` and be discarded. This will repeat ad-nauseum until all the rows have been discarded and none of them will ever be considered to have a higher `ROWNUM` than 1.

For it to work you need to consider that `ROWNUM` is applied before the `ORDER BY` clause takes effect; so, if you want to number the ordered rows then firstly apply the `ORDER BY` then, in an outer query, assign the `ROWNUM` then finally, in further outer query, filter on the that number:

```
SELECT NEWDATE
FROM   (
  SELECT NEWDATE,
         ROWNUM AS RN -- Assign the ROWNUM in the outer query after the ORDER BY
  FROM   (
    SELECT   NEWSDATE
    FROM     NEWS
    WHERE    NEWSNO='100000' AND (CAT='LR' OR CRT ='LD')
    ORDER BY NEWSDATE ASC
  )
  WHERE RN <= 5 -- This WHERE clause is not necessary but might make it more efficient as
                -- it can immediately stop filtering and discard all rows after the 5th.
)
WHERE  RN = 5; -- Then in a further outer query filter on RN
```

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of `ROWNUM` is incorrect. Please read this [article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html) to understand how it works.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT NEWSDATE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWSDATE) AS RN
          FROM NEWS
         WHERE NEWSNO = '100000'
           AND (CAT = 'LR' OR CRT = 'LD')
         ORDER BY NEWSDATE ASC)
 WHERE RN = 5;
```

Comment: The `ROWNUM` is assigned before the `ORDER BY` clause is applied so `RN=5` will not return the 5th row in `NEWDATE` order.

Comment: @MT0: Missed out the part which said he needed the 5th row. So had just removed the error. Edited for getting the 5th row.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 select * from ( 
       select a.*, rownum rnum  from ( 
            SELECT NEWSDATE  FROM NEWS  
            WHERE NEWSNO='100000' AND (CAT='LR' OR CRT ='LD')  
            ORDER BY  NEWSDATE ASC ) 
          where rownum <= 5 )
    where rnum >= 5
```

Comment: This will never return any rows. It will consider the first row produced and discard it as `ROWNUM=1` and then it will consider the second row produced and, since the first row was discarded, will also have `ROWNUM=1` and be discarded. Repeat ad-nauseum.