# Sql query to fetch second latest entry from a table

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata

I have a table with below mentioned columns. I want to fetch the previous status of customer. Once customer id can have multiple entries

```
Customer_id   status     start_date    end_date   Active
1             Member      01-JAN-18    04-FEB-18   N
1             Explorist   05-FEB-18    30-APR-18   N
1             Globalist   01-MAY-18    31-DEC-99   Y
```

Desired output

```
Customer _id     Previous_status   end_date
1                Explorist          30-APR-18
```

Comment: This is not a proper question for SO, show us your attempt to solve this instead of you just expecting others to do the work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below query using QUALIFY keyword and ROW_NUMBER():

```
SELECT a.* from table a 
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id order by start_date desc) = 2
```

Comment: QUALIFY keyword does not work with Oracle. Is it some Teradata propriety keyword?

Comment: You can use a subquery for other database : - 
select * from (
SELECT a.* , ROW_NUMBER OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id order by start_date desc) sno from table a ) where sno = 2

Comment: @Johan: Yup, it's proprietary, it's a filter after Windowed Aggregates, similar to filter after aggregation using HAVING.

Answer (score 0):

Below query should work.

```
SELECT * from (
SELECT a.*, 
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by customer_id order by start_date desc) rn
 from table a ) 
where rn =2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query and I guess that is very simple and that worked for me,

```
select * from customer order by end_date desc limit 1,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this question: [Select Nth Row From A Table In Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509167/select-nth-row-from-a-table-in-oracle)

In your case, that would be:

```
select * from (select a.*, rownum rnum from (select * from <your table name> 
order by <start_date or end_date> desc) a where rownum <= 2) where rnum >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle DataBase then try below query using **ROW_NUMBER()** function:Let's consider the table name is **customer**

```
    SELECT TEMP.CUSTOMER_ID
          ,TEMP.STATUS
          ,TEMP.START_DATE
          ,TEMP.END_DATE
          ,TEMP.ACTIVE 
          FROM(
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID ASC,START_DATE DESC) AS "ROW_NUM"
                  ,CUSTOMER_ID
                  ,STATUS
                  ,START_DATE
                  ,END_DATE
                  ,ACTIVE
                  FROM CUSTOMER) TEMP 
                      WHERE TEMP."ROW_NUM" = 2;
```